# Can't able to install handlebarjs using Bower

Tags: handlebars.js, bower

I'm trying to install handlebarjs package using Bower. I'm getting the following error.

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: are u behind some proxy?

Comment: Yes. I can access Github from browser, also I can install other bower packages

Comment: If your behind a browser u may need to set the proxy for git and bower. That was an issue i faced at my company.

Comment: I could able to successfully install from my home. I wish I could accept your comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You my need to set proxy for both git and bower

For git

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<domain>%5C<username>:<password>@proxy.server.com:8080
git config --global https.proxy http://<domain>%5C<username>:<password>@proxy.server.com:8080
```

Edit your .bowerrc file ( should be next to your bower.json file ) and add the wanted proxy configuration

```
"proxy":"http://<host>:<port>",
"https-proxy":"http://<host>:<port>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try installing using the direct github URL

```
bower install https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/
```

Comment: I think it's the proxy issue. I could able to successfully install from my home.